# C#: update Console in textbox from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

In my application I am trying to show the output of the console into a win forms textbox. This is working as long as I am in the gui thread. But when I write to the console from an other thread, I get an InvalidOperationException. This is the code i use:

in form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Crawler crawler = new Crawler();
        Log log = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log = new Log(tbLogOutput);    
            Console.SetOut(log);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Textwriter:

```
class Log : TextWriter
    {
        TextBox _output = null;

        public Log(TextBox output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            _output.AppendText(value.ToString()); // When character data is written, append it to the text box.
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth typing into Google "Update UI from thread c#"

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: No because I want to write to the console which is updating the ui